# Expo ImagePicker is not opening on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo

Im using expo`s ImagePicker and it is working on android, but it doesn't open anything on IOS, i checked the example on their site and it doesnt seen to work as well

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker

I am trying to upload an image and get the base64 returned back to me

How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If anyone runs into this issue,

my problem was that i didn't request the CAMERA_ROLL permission from the user, which is required for IOS...

Here is an example:

```
const {status_roll} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);

    ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: "Images",
        base64: true
    })
        .then(res => {
            if(onComplete) {
                return onComplete(res.base64)
            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            if (onError) {
                return onError(err);
            }
        })
```